# Python 'int32' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql

In Python-MySQL, I have defined a table as follows:

```
TABLES['clusters'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `clusters` ("
    "  `pid` int(8) NOT NULL, "
    "  `cluster` int(8), "
    "  `cluster_round` varchar(32), "
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`), "
    "  FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`) "
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

for name, ddl in TABLES.iteritems():
    self.cursor.execute(ddl)
```

I now want to add a row as follows:

```
def set_clustering(self, clustering_dict, cluster_round):
    query = (
        "INSERT INTO clustering " 
        "(pid, cluster, cluster_round) "
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s) " 
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cluster = cluster")

    for (pid, cluster) in clustering_dict.iteritems():
        self.cursor.execute(query, (pid, cluster, cluster_round))
    self.cnx.commit()
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 
Failed processing format-parameters; 
Python 'int32' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

Is there an error in my syntax?

Comment: Just a question about storing your schema in a dict. If you have references between tables (as you do), how do you make sure that `persons` exists before you create `clusters`?

Comment: I don't have an answer to that, I am also still looking for that. As a workaround, I just create the tables twice.

Comment: You could try a `collections.OrderedDict` or just a list.

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem. its probably because you're trying to insert numpy int32 and mysql cant support it. you can convert a numpy int to python int by running `numpyint.item()`.

i would recommend checking the type of each variable you're trying to insert (`type(foo)`) to make sure all the values are of type that mysql can support.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to one of the sh**ty drivers for mysql. My very opinionated solution. Update to python 3 and use mysqlclient `pip install mysqlclient` and the problem will be solved! Voila!